# HTML Agility Pack select all header?

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I have a complex HTML document, has so many headings, can `HTMLAgilityPack` select all of headings in one time query?
The result should keep the heading's orginal sequence.

Can anyone know this? thanks

Comment: Please provide part of the HTML or the link you refer it.

Comment: <h1>test1</h1>
<h2>noaml2</h2>
<h3>t3xxx</h3>
<h4>t4dafdsf</h4>
<h1>test2</h1>
……

Comment: just like this simple html string, my real file has the same structure.

Comment: the normal select method is documentNode.selectnodes("//h1") or documentNode.selectnodes("//h2") and so on, but i want to select all headings in one time. is any way for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can do something like this using XPath

```
var xpath = "//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4]";
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
  //do something
}
```

This respect the order of the tags too. If you want more tags you can add it to the Xpath expression.